# Bootstrap Carousel ZoomIn to FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey so i'm customizing the Bootstrap Carousel to have a custom transition effect but am having a hard time achieving it. I believe this is do to my lack of understanding on how the carousel works exactly. Anyways the effect that I am trying to achieve is a simple **fade out** which I found many examples of except the difference is the image will **zoom in** before it **fades out** into the next image.

In other words the image will have a `transition: scale(1)` to `transition: scale(1.1)` then it will `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` into the next image.

I got 3 random images on google just to play around with and it seems that there are 2 problems here.

1. the transition is not smooth
2. the image will scale back down before it fades out into the next image.

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWezyZ

**My CSS:**

```
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*
inspired from http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb 
*/

.carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.carousel-inner .item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: transform 10s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 10s linear;
  -o-transition: transform 10s linear;
  transition: transform 10s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.active img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/*
WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
now override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
*/

@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
    transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
  }
}

/* just for demo purpose */

html,
body,
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 100%;
}

img { width: 100% !important; }
```

This has been quite the challenge because again I lack the "understanding" on how the bootstrap carousel is actually working.

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here [Codepen](http://codepen.io/grebre0/pen/mWVGEz)

Note: notice additional line in JavaScript and remove `active` class from html

Comment: Thats a great edit but you see how before it transitions to the next slide the current slide will scale back down briefly. It's suppose to just scale up then transition onto the next slide without it scaling down.

Comment: Yep. But that's all I could do with `transition`. I would not recommend to use `animation` here (due to performance). U could try ease-in timing function.

Comment: Tried that and no luck. I have seen other websites achieve this with the owl carousel + CSS3 I just couldn't see the code clearly because it was done with angular and all minified.

Comment: Owl is much more powerful. Bootstrap carousel only changes the `.active` class of item and relay on css basically.

Comment: Using owl carousel would be interesting except I don't see how that effect can be achieved using it.

Comment: I don't know owl api well, so not much help from me. I've remembered that I made similar slider on pure css (but you should know the exact number of slides). If you are interested here the codePen http://codepen.io/grebre0/pen/pegxqK